# HTML Dropdown menu using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why doesn't this code work? I copied this code from bootstrap. It works if I don't add the css reference, but shows only plain text. When I ass the css reference, the menu disappears.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dropdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: two references to the same css file?

Comment: Doesn't Bootstrap also use a js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation for bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

> jQuery required
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

It looks like you need to include this still. Try adding the following line of code to your html right before the close body tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments you should also include the bootstrap.js file. That looks like:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: they'll also need to include `bootstrap.js` otherwise jQuery won't do anything

Comment: I recommend opening a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and reproducing your issue. It will be easier to help from that.

Comment: @alu I went ahead and setup a plunker that I think is *something* like what you want. It works and demonstrates the idea. Best of luck! http://plnkr.co/edit/3gJLvI0MxKzSBxLSeJ3d?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jQuery and the bootstrap.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both css and js  reference in the head of the page  :

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `bootstrap.js` and jQuery file reference in the `<head>` tag. and include only one `bootstrap.css` reference.
2. Why have you added class `sr-only` to the button, removing it works.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMKHv/)**

Answer (score -1):

this is a simple dropdown menu 
**CSS:**

```
body{
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:right;
}
#a{
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#0F0;
    opacity:0.8;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px;

}
#nav ul{
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    background:#000;
    padding:0px;
}
#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
    background:#000;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background:#999;
}

#nav ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#nav a{
    line-height:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mobile view</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">categories</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Cat 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Cat 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/72Khc/)

Comment: What's this got to do with the question? The OP isn't asking for someone to write a dropdown for them, they want to know why their code isn't working.